# Enabling iCloud Sync for Voice Memos, deleted many recordings!

Tags: icloud, voice-memo

For many years I've used the Voice Memo app to record quick things I encounter in life.  These events are of course, one-off things that can't be reproduced again, so the recordings are important to me.

Just now, I went to look for a voice memo from a year or two ago.  I got a pop up asking me if I wanted to enable iCloud sync for voice memos.  My suspicion for why I got this message, was that earlier this year I purchased an iCloud subscription and enabled iCloud backups for the first time ever on my phone, but had not launched the voice memos app since.  I figured it was a feature now active because I had somewhere to sync stuff to (I could be totally wrong in this theory however).

I said yes because why would one not want your memos synced to iCloud, and the app came up.  But, it has only about a dozen memos in it, and none later than 2020.  In particular, the one that I was looking for, is totally gone.

A quick Google revealed that I'm not alone in this:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253914202

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252875370

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250886054

The third item here, might not be exactly the same as what I encountered, but still seems quite similar.

There are no deleted recordings to recover.  There are no voice memos anywhere on icloud.com.  Voice memos for icloud was never enabled prior to right now.

I'm not about to attempt a full restore of my phone, as multiple past experiences with this has shown me that in so doing I would be forced to upgrade to the most recent iOS, and I'm on iOS 14 and unwilling to use 15.

- Does anyone know how/why this would happen, and how to prevent it in the future?
- Is there any way to find and recover the missing memos?

Comment: If you have or could borrow another iOS device, you could restore to it, then try syncing again. That might save your memos.

Comment: Yeah... there's a small chance I might actually be able to do that, though I don't have much faith in that restoring the recordings.  If they were available to be restored, why would they not be there now?  I even enabled iCloud sync on my mac and only the memos I can see in my phone, appeared.  I'll look into it regardless though, thanks.

Comment: But if they’re in the backup, they should reappear after the restore.

Comment: But if they were in the backup, wouldn't they have appeared on any other device that I enabled iCloud sync for voice memos on?  Because that definitely didn't happen.  And I suppose there is no way to see into the backup without restoring it?  Now I want to look into that.

Comment: Just to add to this, I took a look at the contents of my backup in the Manage iCloud section in Settings on my phone.  There are loads of apps listed, but Voice Memo is NOT one of them!  That app doesn't even appear to be getting backed up at all.

Comment: No, they wouldn't have appeared. They're gone, except in your backup. So you'll have to reload your backup to get them back. And they may be lumped into a general system section, as it's an Apple app.

Comment: Just for completion, I finally tried restoring to another iOS device.  Unfortunately, it's not able to run a modern enough version of iOS, to restore the backup.  Looks like I'm just out of luck unless I upgrade my actual phone's OS, which I'm not willing to do.  Suck.

Comment: Ugh. I suppose you could impose on a friend who has a device that can run the latest OS to back up his device, hand it to you to restore your image, sync the memos with iCloud, then wipe it and hand it back to him to restore his own backup.

Comment: Yeah don't have anyone that fits that description unfortunately.  Though now I'm wondering if I could buy a new phone, do what I need, and return it within the return period.  Hmmm.